# Facing 403 error while Indeed web scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I need to do the web scraping using request in 'https://in.indeed.com/'. When I'm running the code it shows the 403 error

Can anyone tell me the solution..

```
url = "https://in.indeed.com"

hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

result = requests.get(url,headers = hdr)

print(result)
```

I have tried till this to check the status code of the website only it shows error

Note: Need to do the web scraping without using selenium

Comment: You asked the same question previously - this is a duplicate. Indeed is using Cloudflare to protect itself from scraping. They offer an API for developers - visit https://developer.indeed.com/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are some headers missing in your request. I also get a 403 when i do the request like that. However, a copied cURL request works:

***Try the following:***

1. Open the website in Chrome (or Firefox)
2. Open the developers console
3. Copy the request from the first GET
   (4. You can try out the cURL request in your console. It worked for me without any 403)
4. Set the headers similar to the cURL request in your code

[image]

(However, i'm assuming the take some measures against web scraping. So you may run in further problems. I'm guessing that you also have to save the cookie or something like this.)

Comment: After applying the all headers and cookies also still it shows the 403 error

Comment: but it worked in your shell (copying the cURL command from dev tools)?

Comment: I just copy the curl all command from bash and then paste it in curl converter to convert it into a code and then i run that code it still shows 403 error

Comment: As I copied the cURL(cmd) it doesn't runs in terminal also cannot able to convert it into code

Comment: Can you please provide more details, do you got the same 403 when you run it in terminal? It worked for me. (Please make sure you copy the right cULR for your console, e.g. cmd/bash/ps.. or try it out in Node.js or fetch)

Comment: P.S. for me it worked in bash (i did not try it out in cmd as it is marked in the screenshot just for example).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why Indeed could be blocking your requests. You can use a combination of the methods described in this article to fetch the data

1. Easy Way To Solve 403 Forbidden Errors When Web Scraping
2. Use Fake User Agents
3. Optimize Request Headers
4. Use Rotating Proxies

For more details check this article

[https://scrapeops.io/web-scraping-playbook/403-forbidden-error-web-scraping/](https://%20https://scrapeops.io/web-scraping-playbook/403-forbidden-error-web-scraping/)